# Selection does not contain a main type

Tags: java, maven, eclipse, telegram

Есть два класса, Main, bot

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;

public class bot extend TelegramLongPollingBot {
public void onUpdateReceived(org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update update) {
    update.getUpdateId();
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage().setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
    
    if(update.getMessage().getText().equals("Привет")) {
        sendMessage.setText("Привет");
        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public String getBotUsername() {
    return "";
}
public String getBotToken() {
    return "";
    
}
}
```

и Main

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContexInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;


public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApiContextInitializer.init();
    org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi telegram = new TelegramBotsApi();
    
    bot bot = new Bot();
    try {
        telegram.registerBot(bot);
    } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

жму ПКМ по main, run as Java Aplication а в ответ получаю  Selection does not contain a main type
но ведь содержится метод main, подскажите, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте щелкнуть правой кнопкой мыши по папке, в которую вы поместили свой основной класс, затем нажмите Путь сборки -> Использовать как исходную папку.